# Fetching the response with peekBody() somehow blocks any following code

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Somewhere in my code I consume the response of a http call:

```
@Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, final okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                    String res = response.peekBody(99999L).string();
                    //String res = response.body().string();
                    Log.d("shalocmo", "okhttp3:" + res);
                    Log.d("shalocmo", "okhttp3: here");
```

First debug line with return string returns perfectly. Second debug line never appears... According to docs and common sense (I don't do anything in between both lines), I don't understand why it would never appear. I don't get any exceptions, or Error messages except the "E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module" message I get all over the place. Can anybody help me out here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `peekBody()` size down to something small, like 99L, and see what happens. There's a good chance that you're trying to peek too much data

Comment: Sadly, still doesn't work

Comment: Regardless, seems like the call worked and I put the result in a String. I can "print" the string and then... nothing. Logcat doesn't show anything relevant.

Comment: ok, try removing the 1st log line, and only leave the 2nd one. Maybe it's crashing once you actually access your peeked response (the exception may be caught somewhere upstream, and never shown in logcat)

Comment: Ok, I was set of by a wrapper function which logged the same, my onresponse is never reached...